# Ambiente local não processa algumas requisições

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Estou trabalhando com 2 sites em Laravel, onde ocorrem solicitações para o servidor de importação e exportação de grandes bases em Excel.

Quando vou fazer alterações nessas bases, não consigo testa-las em minha maquina local, devo subir para o servidor da amazon para depois ver se minhas alterações estão de acordo com o planejado.

Eu imagino que os servidores atendam essas requisições em segundo plano, e  que o ambiente local normalmente não ...

Vocês conhecem algum jeito de habilitar ou simular o processamento dessas requisições que teoricamente são processadas em segundo plano pelo servidor, na minha maquina linux local?

Comment: Qual problema ocorre na sua maquina? Apache expira? Memória enche?
Talvez possamos ajustar o apache para resolver.

Comment: O que seria "requisições em segundo plano"?

Comment: Wallace, gerar uma base em excel por exemplo